# "Step counter" in Esperanto?

Tags: single-word-requests

When I'm talking about my day I need some words that aren't likely found in dictionaries, but that one could put together understandably with a bit of imagination. What would the most accurate translation of step counter be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What is a step counter? It is a *tool* to *count* *steps*.

- steps is *paŝoj*
- to count is *nombri*
- a tool is *ilo*

So *paŝnombrilo* should do the job.